# jquery css behaviour

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

Having a spot of bother with the following code. 
Essentially I have a div container that is height:40px, when I click on it, it smoothly grows to 320px - this works great, however when the div has grown to full height, I then want the overflow property to change from it's static state of hidden, to visible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#join').click(function() {
        $('#join').animate({ height: "320px" }, 500);
        $('#join').css('overflow', 'visible');
    })
});​
```

It does go visible for a few seconds but then disappears, also I want it to happen after the div has grown to full height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the style inside the `animate` callback function.. See below,

```
$(this).animate({height:"320px"}, 500, function () { //this <- #join
   $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
});
```

**Complete code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#join').click(function() {
       $(this).animate({height:"320px"}, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Note that, the first DOM query can be avoid as well.

Comment: @PeteNorris. Family hug... :)

Answer (score 3):

Then pass it as a callback:

```
$(this).animate({height:"320px"}, 500, function(){
    $(this).css('overflow', 'visible')
});
```

**Full code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#join').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "320px"
        }, 500, function() {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Typo :P `{);` in `$(this).animate({height:"320px"}, 500, function(){);
`

Comment: @Vega. You meant _"by whole 3 seconds!"_ `:-)`